# jQuery autocomplete text boxes: triggering the autocomplete of one textbox based on the input of another

Tags: jquery, jsp, autocomplete

I have two textboxes, `tbox1` and `tbox2`, that have jQuery autocomplete applied on them. Based on the characters or string the user enters, autocompletes suggestions would be fetched from a database. This part is implemented by having individual JSP pages for `tbox1` and `tbox2` that retrieve data from the database.

Now say `tbox1` has a value "Paul", I would like this value to be passed to the autocomplete functionality of `tbox2` (rather, to the JSP that retrieves the value of `tbox2`) so that I can base my SQL for data retrieval on the value of `tbox1`.

How do I achieve this?
[EDIT] -- My current code is as follows --
JSP --

```
<tr>
 <td  align="right" height="26">
 <font face="verdana, arial, helvetica">
 <font color="#000000" face="Trebuchet MS">
 <small>
TargetLocations:  </small> </font> </font> </td>
<td ><font face="verdana, arial, helvetica">
  <input type="text" class="text46" id="targetloc" name="targetloc" value="<%= targetloc%>">
  </font></td>

</tr>
<script>
        $("#targetloc").autocomplete("getfcs.jsp");
</script>
```

And the corresponding JSP `getfcs.jsp` has logic to retrieve the values from the database.

I have another similar textbox `targetSites` that is serviced by a JSP verey similar to getfcs.jsp as showmn above.
Now I guess all i would want is for the value of targetloc to be passed within the JSP so that i can consume the same.

Any pointers ?

Comment: can you show us the code you have and may show us what you have tried already ?

Comment: You can use `$.map()` to combine 2 arrays with each other.

Comment: I can only see one text box here where is the second one?

Comment: The code you present does not match your problem description at all.
When you run the code you have what happens?
Have you looked at the (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)documentation for autocomplete?] There is a required option to the `autocomplete()` function which you do not properly assign.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=48&title=Dependent%20Select%20-%20Dependent%20Dropdowns%20-%20Triple%20Select%20Using%20Jqueryhttp://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=48&title=Dependent%20Select%20-%20Dependent%20Dropdowns%20-%20Triple%20Select%20Using%20Jquery) might help you. Although it uses select rather than autocompleter but it should do the trick.